# Как применить оператор побитового сдвига в Java?

Tags: java, системы-счисления

Говорят, что в Java есть оператор побитового сдвига  `<<`.
Он, в теории, может сдвинуть влево (`>>` - вправо) двоичное число. К примеру, 1010 преобразовать в 10100.
Это я и хочу сделать: пытаюсь написать простенькую программу, которая сдвинет на бит (влево или вправо) число:

```
public class Binary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0B1010; //запись числа в двоичной системе исчисления
        x << 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Но выдаётся ошибка компиляции, как бы я ни переписывал код.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Пишите код правильно:

```
public class Binary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0B1010; //запись числа в двоичной системе исчисления
        x = x << 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

А если хотите увидеть в двоичной системе, тогда выводите так:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));
```

Comment: В дополнение: в отличие от C/C++, Java не позволяет даже скомпилировать явную бессмыслицу, коей является выражение `x << 1;`. Проблема этого выражения в том, что его результат ничему не присваивается, пропадает, на что и ругается компилятор (кстати, хорошим тоном было бы привести в вопросе сообщение об ощибке: `error: not a statement`). Как только вы присваиваете результат какой-нибудь переменной - всё становится ок.

Comment: Спасибо. А я где-то почти подбирался к такому. Но без вас всё равно нашел бы не раньше чем через неделю.

Comment: К сожалению, в Java встроенна только примитивная проверка на подобные ошибки. Если объявить метод, который к примеру просто умножает аргумент на два и вызвать его, то компилятор проглотит подобное и ничего не скажет.

    private static int test(int a) {
        return a << 1;
    }
    //....
   test(3);

Comment: Глубокий анализ сайд-эффектов методов сильно усложнил бы жизнь компилятору, так что он отсекает только совсем уж явный бред. Но, всё же, это лучше, чем ничего.

Answer (score 8):

Как вариант, можно ещё воспользоваться оператором `<<=`:

```
public class Binary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0B1010; //запись числа в двоичной системе исчисления
        x <<= 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: тоже тема. Запускается главное.

Comment: Оператор ёлочка :)